# App exits while launching in TV Box

Tags: android, android-tv, tvbox

The error is shown below.

```
ANR in com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.android (com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.android/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.splashpage.SplashActivity)
PID: 7892
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
Load: 0.66 / 0.81 / 0.76
CPU usage from 4152ms to -4853ms ago:
 20% 3111/system_server: 7.7% user + 13% kernel / faults: 4972 minor 2 major
 0% 2789/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3092 minor 2 major
 0.1% 3932/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 884 minor
 2.1% 7892/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android: 0.6% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 2854 minor
 0.8% 3288/com.android.systemui: 0.3% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1209 minor
 0.9% 2763/logd: 0.8% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3 minor
 0% 3409/com.droidlogic.inputmethod.remote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 935 minor
 0% 3427/com.droidlogic.service.remotecontrol: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 935 minor
 0% 3447/com.droidlogic.SubTitleService: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 932 minor
 0.6% 7495/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
 0.4% 2791/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 1 minor
 0.3% 1842/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
 0.2% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
 0.2% 3468/com.droidlogic.mboxlauncher: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 641 minor
 0% 896/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
 0.1% 1722/kthread_h265: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
 0.1% 3868/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
 0% 4034/usbtestpm: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 127 minor
+0% 8015/dex2oat: 0% user + 0% kernel
68% TOTAL: 52% user + 12% kernel + 3.7% iowait
CPU usage from 4120ms to 4634ms later:
 5.7% 7892/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android: 0% user + 5.7% kernel / faults: 260 minor
   5.7% 7892/inehome.android: 0% user + 5.7% kernel
 2.8% 2763/logd: 1.4% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor
   2.8% 5820/logd.reader.per: 2.8% user + 0% kernel
 3.8% 3111/system_server: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 2 minor
   1.9% 3123/FinalizerDaemon: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
   1.9% 3127/Binder_1: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
   1.9% 3130/ActivityManager: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
 1.5% 3932/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 1.5% user + 0% kernel
 1.6% 7495/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
+0% 8005/dex2oat: 0% user + 0% kernel
52% TOTAL: 42% user + 6.6% kernel + 3.3% iowait
```

When first time the app launches it works. The app exits When app launches after clicking the home button on the remote, while the app is running.
If we try the same process for 3 times it works normally.
Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Can you share some code to show us what you have tried?

Comment: We dont know where the code breaks, then which code we have to show?

Comment: Then I think you are asking in the wrong place. Have a look at what is acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code on manifest

```
  android:clearTaskOnlaunch="true"
```

for each activity
example:-

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.SplashActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnlaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```